# Custom post URL 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, 404-error

I have custom post type and custom taxonomy. Categories works well but posts give me 404. I dont know why. It worked before I define URL for hiearchical categories. Can anybody help me? Main fragments of code is below.

```
function produkty() {
    $labels = array(...);
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'slug' => 'kategorie', 'with_front' => false ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('produkty', array('podlahy'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'produkty', 0);

    function podlahy() {

    $labels = array(...);
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Podlahy', 'idrevenepodlahy'),
        'description' => __('Podlahy', 'idrevenepodlahy'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail',),
        'taxonomies' => array('produkty'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'kategorie/%produkty%', 'with_front' => true),
        'has_archive' => 'kategorie',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );
    register_post_type('podlahy', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'podlahy', 0);


function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'podlahy' ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->id , 'produkty');
    $link = "";
        if( $terms ){
$parent = $terms[0]->term_id;
$parent2 = $terms[0]->parent;
$parent3 = 0;
$link = $terms[0]->slug;

if($parent2 > 0){
$terms = get_term( $parent2 );
$link = $terms->slug ."/". $link;
$parent3 = $terms->parent;
}

if($parent3 > 0){
$terms = get_term( $parent3 );
$link = $terms->slug ."/". $link;
}

            return str_replace( '%produkty%' , $link , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```